# Error while showing a modal dialog box or form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am checking emailId exists in DB, If Exists
I am looking to create a Ok/Cancel confirmation dialog.
if user say "Ok" I am redirecting to some other form.

My code is :

```
If emailId = True Then
    If MsgBox("Your email address exists in our database. Click OK to update your   Details.", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkCancel, Title:="NJ Golf Resort") = MsgBoxResult.Ok Then
        Response.Redirect("~/articles.asp?a=" & a & "&b=" & b )
    End If
End If
```

for above code i m getting error :

> Showing a modal dialog box or form
>   when the application is not running in
>   UserInteractive mode is not a valid
>   operation. Specify the
>   ServiceNotification or
>   DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a
>   notification from a service
>   application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function redirect(a,b){
      if(confirm('Your email id is in DB')){
          window.location.href='/articles.asp?a='+a+'&b='+b;
       }
}
```

In serverside call the above client side function as

```
If emailId = True Then
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EmailID", String.Format("redirect({0},{1});", aValue, bValue), true);

    /*For Asp.net AJAX use the following code*/
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EmailID", String.Format("redirect({0},{1});", aValue, bValue), true);
```

End If

Note:I have given the C# code.Translate to VB.

Comment: Added  /*For Asp.net AJAX use the following code*/    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "EmailID", String.Format("redirect({0},{1});", aValue, bValue), true);
------------- 
i m getting following error  ----> wucEmailSignUp.ascx.vb(40): error BC30456: 'ClientScript' is not a member of 'System.Web.UI.ScriptManager'.

Comment: ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "as", "script", true); this Should work 
Remove the line 
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(....... For AJAX only the above line is enough

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a website code in ASP.Net, and what you are trying to do is display msgbox on server, this can not be done as the user is interacting with the web browser on client side, you may better use javascript to dispaly msgbox

Cheers.

Comment: i know writing javascript for validations like required fields.
in this case i have to do coding in back end .
step 1 : Check for EmailId existance in DB.If Exists
step 2 : Show a message to user saying 
         "Your email address exists in our database. Click OK to update your Details"  If user press OK then i have to redirect them to contact page.

If u have any samples,let me know

Comment: I need to do this task using AJAX .I m not getting how to do this for following condition using AJAX.
step 1 : Check for EmailId existance in DB.If Exists             step 2 : Show a message to user saying "Your email address exists in our database. Click OK to update your Details" If user press OK then i have to redirect them to contact page.

Comment: call a http post or webservice (which returns true if email id already exists) from javascript use XMLHttpRequest object. If true display msgbox. Refer to the answer by Kusek.

http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/ajax_intro.asp

look at the example there, hope it helps :)

Comment: I have Updated the Code for AJAX.

Comment: using <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>  and <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>.after verifying EmailId in DB with code behind if emailId exists in DB, then i should pop up ModalPopupExtender for confirmaion.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, you shouldn't be using `System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox` in an ASP.NET application, because message boxes will only work properly for Windows Forms applications.