# Asp.net error using Visual Basic Input Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have used a Visual Basic Reference in C# to Add a Location to a Table.
This works Locally but after Publishing it to the Hosting Site it produces this Error:
Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.

My code is as follows:

```
        string addlocation = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Enter New Location", "Location", "", 600, 400);
        if (addlocation == "" || addlocation == null)
        {
            Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("Enter a Valid Name!", 0);
            return;
        }
        using (var connection3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Locations WHERE Locations = '" + addlocation + "'", connection);
            Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count == 0)
            using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Locations(Locations) VALUES('" + addlocation + "');", connection3))
            {
                connection3.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection3.Close();
                Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                connection3.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox("Location Already Exists!", 0);
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This is a web site? You can't show those kinds of dialogs. Nobody would see them even if it was not causing an error. You see it on your local pc because you are interactively logged onto the server.

Comment: ... and use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors in your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your using VB msgbox while it has been replaced with MessageBox.Show. You get get more help in below -

[Issue with Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.MsgBox method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721540/issue-with-microsoft-visualbasic-interaction-msgbox-method)

Comment: MessageBox.Show isn't likely to work any better in the context of ASP.NET

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. Sorry I am new (relatively to Asp.net and certainly Deployment to a Host Site). I have been involved in Computing since 1980 and may appear an idiot to most of the younger generation. but if they ever need help with Fortran, Cobol, DEC DCL (VMS) or even the old HP Basic programming I will be able to help. The point is Concepts are hard to assimilate e.g. When the first Browser was released in the 1990's it took me ages to grasp what it was all about. In essence I need to be guided toward enlightenment. Regards Jim

Comment: PS: The replies are all about Message Boxes not Requests for Input to add to a SQL Server Table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code behind runs in server-side, you cannot use both `InputBox` and `MsgBox` methods to show input or alert box in client-side browser. I recommend to use JS `prompt` as input box replacement, or use your own modal dialog containing text input (e.g. Bootstrap modal) and then use `alert` function to show messages instead.

Here is an example to show prompt and redirect into code-behind method:

```
var location = prompt("Enter New Location", "");

// check against null or empty value
if (location == null || location == "")
{
    alert("Enter a Valid Name!");
}
else
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pagename.aspx/CheckLocation",
        data: "{'location':'" + location + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.d == true) {
                // show alert box
                alert("Location Already Exists!");
            }
            else {
                // redirect to another page
                window.location.href = '<%= Request.Url.ToString() %>';
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, err) {
            // error handling
        }
    });
}
```

Code-behind

```
[WebMethod]
public bool CheckLocation(string location)
{
    bool LocationExists = false;
    using (var connection3 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Locations WHERE Locations = @location", connection);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", location);
        int count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());

        if (count == 0)
        {
            using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Locations(Locations) VALUES(@addlocation)", connection3))
            {
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addlocation", location);
                connection3.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            LocationExists = true;
        }
    }

    return LocationExists;
}
```

Related issue:

[Error while showing a modal dialog box or form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030891/error-while-showing-a-modal-dialog-box-or-form)

Comment: Thanks Tetsuya but I could not get your solution to work, however I did find the answer using Javascript!

Answer (score 0):

Solved using script as Follows:

```
<title></title>
<script>
 function GetUserValue() {
   var newlength = prompt("Please Enter New Length", "");
   if (newlength != null && newlength != "") {
     document.getElementById("<%=hdnLengthInput.ClientID%>").value = newlength;
     return true;
  }
  else
  return false;
 }
</script>

<div>
 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnLengthInput" />
</div>

And Then in the .CS file:

protected void lnkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(hdnLengthInput.Value);
        using (var connection3 = new 
SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Categories WHERE 
Length = '" + hdnLengthInput.Value + "'", connection);
            Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar());

            if (count == 0)
                using (var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Categories(Length) 
VALUES('" + hdnLengthInput.Value + "');", connection3))
                {
                    connection3.Open();
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    connection3.Close();
                    Page.Response.Redirect(Page.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                }

            connection.Close();
        }
     }
```